# Dealing with Artifacts in The Render?

Tags: rendering, mesh, vertices, artifacts

Please help, I am going insane trying to deal with this. I am pretty new to blender but i've just completed building a character. The face is pretty intricate and I had a feeling it was going to be a problem come rendering time.

I'm now trying to deal with a bunch of artifacts showing up on the face (like those above the eyebrow),
[image: See above the eyebrow]

Luckily, it's only the face that's showing this problem. Unluckily I can't seem to find a solution. I've spent the last 5 hours going in and deleting and dissolving edges and vertices and at the end of that period it looked no better, the issues had just moved to new locations on the face. Can anyone offer some insight? if I just knew what the issue was I could start trying to fix it properly. Right now I just feel like i'm trying to blunder through to a solution.

Comment: Hey, it looks like your normals are backwards. That probably won't fix the whole problem but try selecting everything and hitting Ctrl + N.

Comment: Thank you for your help Pycoder and Anson. I will give these things a try. Anson, as I am trying to learn more about how to use this program properly, can you tell me what exactly you see in that picture that made you think the normals were wrong? That way I know what to look for in the future. I applied the subdivision but it made everything too cluttered/overwhelming to deal with going in to remove the vertices so i turned it off. I've changed to mesh view as you said. Due to the nature of the model I was finding it hard to get at the vertices inside the model so I went through the back of t

Comment: There are faces that look very dark on the front part of the model. A normal is basically the direction a face is showing. The shading is off when they are backwards. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is all about that evil word good modelers often use:

### Topology

Here are some ways to improve this:

1. Do some research on [good *mesh topology* techniques](https://www.google.com/?client=safari#q=good%20mesh%20topology%20in%20blender) and **USE THEM**
2. Use smooth shading
3. Your model looks far to detailed right now (as far as vertex count)...try removing some of the edge loops, and adding a [subdivision surface modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html)
4. A lot of your trouble is coming from vertices that are actually inside the mesh...try switching to wireframe view to pull these out (if you cleanup your mesh and use a subsurf, this will be **much** easier to do
5. Finally, like Anson said, you should be checking your normals often...hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

The technique of modeling with a subsurf modifier is huge!